# makefile hangs when calling shell command head

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to print the first line of some text file from within my `makefile`.
Here's what I have, and it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ cat makefile
BASEDIR = ${HOME}/Downloads
MYDIR = ${BASEDIR}/ddd
all:
    var=${MYDIR}/m.txt
    @echo $(shell head -n 1 ${var})
#   @echo $(shell head -n 1 ${MYDIR}/m.txt)
```

When I try to use `make` it simply hangs and I have to kill it.
When I remove the comment and use the `head` command directly on `${MYDIR}/m.txt` everything works fine. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Tangentially, don't use `@` to silence `make`, especially while debugging. Once you know exactly what's going on, you probably want to use `make -s` if you don't want to see what's happening.

Comment: I prefer this method of dealing with recipe echoing: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use the `shell` make function in recipes. Recipes are already shell scripts:

```
BASEDIR := $(HOME)/Downloads
MYDIR   := $(BASEDIR)/ddd

all:
    @var="$(MYDIR)/m.txt"; head -n 1 "$$var"
```

Notes:

- Recipes are expanded by make before they are passed to the shell. This is where `$(MYDIR)` will be replaced by something like `/home/doe/Downloads/ddd/m.txt`. And this is why `$var` would not work. It would expand as `ar`, unless there is a make variable named `v` with a non-empty value `FOO`, in which case `$var` would expand as `FOOar`. `$$var` is expanded by make as `$var`, the shell syntax you want.
- Each line of a recipe is executed by an independent shell. The following would thus not work:

  ```
  all:
      @var="$(MYDIR)/m.txt"
      @head -n 1 "$$var"
  ```

  because the shell variable assignment (`var="/home/doe/Downloads/ddd/m.txt"`) and the shell variable expansion (`head -n 1 "$var"`) would be executed by two different shells. If you want one single shell statement per line, use the line continuation:

  ```
  all:
      @var="$(MYDIR)/m.txt"; \
      head -n 1 "$$var"
  ```

  or:

  ```
  all:
      @var="$(MYDIR)/m.txt" && \
      head -n 1 "$$var"
  ```

Comment: It is of course dubious whether putting the string in a variable and only using it once is any use at all, but I'll just leave this comment here. (^8

Comment: @tripleee: agreed. But I suspect the real Makefile will be different, at the end. So, let's show how to properly use shell variables in make recipes, it is always good to know.

Comment: how come I can't extend the solution to: `x=$(head -n 1 "$$var"); echo $$x'

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: you can... if you properly escape **all** `$` signs: `x=$$(head -n 1 "$$var"); echo "$$x"`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use variable assignments in recipes. In your command `head -n 1 ${var}` the expression `${var}` expands to nothing and hence `head` waits on standard input. The following makefile should work:

```
BASEDIR = ${HOME}/Downloads
MYDIR = ${BASEDIR}/ddd
var=${MYDIR}/m.txt
all:
    @echo $(shell head -n 1 ${var})
```

Comment: You still want to avoid using `$(shell)` in the recipe. The [`echo` is also useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)